# Escaping slash error in Redshift PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am getting this error while inserting data in Amazon Redshift DB.

Database error: A Database Error Occurred

```
Error Number: 
ERROR:  type "e" does not exist
INSERT INTO "api_data" ("verb", "request", "uri", "user_id", "device_id", "os", "lat", "long", "app_version", "platform", "network_type", "date_added", "response") VALUES ('post',  E'{"prn":"28135","nce":"WqN6YHtXPzz\\/QAqhj1+TNi2p1nL64f3Ttr77IYZz9vzXaF7DpBF2CSss2aclltI3W\\/PgOXaecqW\\/VAmwVqTlow=="}', 'https://dev.kraftly.com/api/v1/Layer/chatAuthEnc', 0, 'NULL', 'iOS 9.1', NULL, NULL, 'Version 2', 'NULL', 'NULL', '2016-03-21 17:26:24', 'NULL')
```

Please provide me any solutions. Thanks

Comment: Please add your table definition to the question editing it.

Answer (score 1):

This probably has to do with using pg_escape_literal. That produces an escaped string with quotes around it. If the string contains a backslash, the whole is prepended by E, as you can see in your query. Redshift apparently cannot handle that.